# From the melee classes (barbarian, fighter, monk, paladin), what subclasses are the most complex to play?

Tags: dnd-5e, class, melee-combat

As the topic states, I'm interested in playing more melee (tanks are hard to find sometimes) but I don't want to run a character like the Champion that does nothing but stand there and hit hard.  Melee characters are generally very simple to play, and I'm hoping to break that mold.

What subclass, for each of the main melee classes, is considered the most complex to play?

A good example may be the Illusion mage vs. Evocation, with Illusion being more "complex".

Comment: I think that what you are asking is not which one is more difficult, but which one is more tactically complex.

Comment: Fair point, will edit to clarify

Comment: Also, answers to this question could lean pretty hard ot the subjective.  You might want to specifically ask for people who've had personal experience playing more than one version of the same class, and which of the subclasses was the more or less technical.

Comment: Also also, as presented, this is actually four questions (one each for barbarian, fighter, monk, paladin).  Once you have it reasonably well-tuned, you should ask each of the four questions separately.  Still, that's not somethign I'd do until you've locked down exactly how you want to ask it.

Comment: I was worried about that, but I didn't feel comfortable with posting 4 of the same question, once for each class. Figured that'd be more annoying than one question with four parts to an answer.

Comment: It's all good.  We'd prefer it as four separate questions.  Welcome to RPG stack exchange.  We have *very particular ideas* of how questions should and should not be... and getting good questions is good.  Getting more good questions is better.

Comment: The other problem with this question (even if split into 4 separate questions by class) is that it seems significantly opinion-based. How do you define "complex"?

Comment: I suppose versatility, level of risk/reward.  A champion, for instance, is super simple, and has little risk involved other than not getting a critical.  A battlemaster could easily waste his resources and end up useless, though.  However, between the battlemaster and the eldritch knight, what might be more difficult to play in this regard?

Comment: One issue with splitting it into 4 questions is that based on what's written at the moment, the *problem OP is facing* is choosing which class & subclass to play. Thus while 4 separate questions might help OP, they do not answer the full question (e.g., because base Monk might be more complex than base Fighter, so if Open Hand & Battlemaster are equally complex subclasses on their own, when paired with the main class Open Hand Monk is more complex). We should be wary of suggesting decomposition into XY questions. @DanielZastoupil, am I on target here or misrepresenting you?

Comment: @Vigil That's a fair assessment, but not all questions are answerable at SE, and sometimes that's just the way it is.  If I refined the question enough so there's no opinions at stake, then it's too narrow to be of any value. And SE isn't in the business of opinions.  So I'd probably find more support for it elsewhere.  Thank you for your support, though.

Comment: You've omitted Rogue and Ranger from your list of melee classes, despite both being viable melee fighters. I presume from your inclusion of Paladin that being a half-caster isn't a deal-breaker. Is there any particular feature you're looking for which you feel the classes you've listed have exclusively? If so that would probably be useful information in judging subclasses.

Comment: @Vigil I'm interested in the classes who have high durability.  The Paladin does have spells, but considering their lack of spell slots and limited versatility, their spells are usually used for melee combat, which is why they were included.  Clerics and Rangers were excluded, since versatility is something they are already proficient in.

Answer (score 2):

In thinking of the ones listed here, Monk generally is the most complicated, at least in terms of decisionmaking. I chose this because I think most characters face a question of how best to use limited resources, but monks get a huge breadth of choice on how to use their resources.

In any given turn tou can spend a single ki point to achieve:

- Disengage
- Dash
- Attack with one extra unarmed strike
- Dodge
- Stunning fist (for each individual hit)

This is just for base class too. If you go Kensai you get more decisions each turn. For subclasses, Elemental Monk and Kensai add the most tactical decisionmaking. Kensai at 3 gives you ranged abilities, but at the sacrifice of some power, or better defense at the sacrifice of power.

As a Monk you have to choose how to spend your ki points, because you can easily spend 6 ki points at level 6 upping your damage on weapon attacks, flurrying and stunning fist attempting on each hit. You can alternatively spend 1 ki point per turn dodging and using your weapon to provide AC. The options are wide and their optimal use is situational.